# Why is this program not playing my music files?

Tags: java, mp3, jlayer

I was trying to create a basic music player in Java using JLayer library, but it doesn't seem to work. Nothing is played when I open a file (.mp3) through JFileChooser. Below is the code for my application. Please tell me what's wrong in it.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;

class MusicPlayer
{
public void Player()
{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try
        {
            File track = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            FileInputStream trackstream = new FileInputStream(track);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedtrack = new BufferedInputStream(trackstream);

            try
            {
                Player player = new Player(bufferedtrack);
            }
            catch(JavaLayerException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Can't open file!");
            }

        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
        }
    } 
    else {

    }
 }
}

public class PlayerApp {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    new MusicPlayer().Player();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did miss out `player.play()` of the [Player](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/docs/docs1.0/javazoom/jl/player/Player.html#play()) to start playing the requested file.

```
try 
{
    Player player = new Player(bufferedtrack);
    player.play(); // add this line
}
catch(JavaLayerException e)
{
    System.out.println("Can't open file!");
}
```

Also, method names are commonly written in [camel-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) (first letter lowercase). I recommend to rename your method `void Player()` to something like `void loadDialogAndPlayFile()`.

Comment: Thanks :) It works now but when I try to close the player, it doesn't close and the music keeps on playing till the end of the track :(

Comment: You can try `player.close()` which stops the current stream from playing.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call the `player.play();` method after `Player player = new Player(bufferedtrack);`

Comment: Whoops! Silly me :P Thanks a lot.